# keep range value shown in materialize

Tags: javascript, slider, range, materialize

I'm using Materialize to display a list of checkboxes with range sliders :

```
{% for keyword in keywords %}
    <div class="col m4 s12">
        <p class="range-field">
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{keyword.id}}" name="{{keyword.title}}" class="filled-in"/>
            <label for="{{keyword.id}}">{{keyword.title}}</label>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100"/>
        </p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

The problem I'm having is that the range value only shows when I'm clicking or moving the range button and it disappears when not. I want it to be always visible

[image] [image]

Comment: Take a look at https://refreshless.com/nouislider/ options. Materialize has used noUiSlider for it's range component.